# Inline formset is not validating when fields are empty

Tags: django

Inline formset is valid when all the fields are empty but when i fill any one field and submit the formset becomes invalid ?

forms.py

```
 class ContactPersonForm(forms.ModelForm):

    phone_number = PhoneNumberField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your phone number'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Mobile Number')}))
    mobile_number = PhoneNumberField(error_messages={'required': 'Please enter your phone number'}, widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Mobile Number')}))

    class Meta:
        model = ContactPerson
        exclude = ('client',)
        widgets = {
            'first_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('First Name')}),
            'last_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Last Name')}),
            'email': forms.EmailInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Email')}),
            'phone_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Phone Number')}),
            'mobile_number': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Mobile Number')}),
            'skype_name': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Skype Name / Number')}),
            'designation': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Designation')}),
            'department': forms.TextInput(attrs={'placeholder': _('Department')}),
        }


  ContactPersonFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, ContactPerson, form=ContactPersonForm, extra=1)
```

models.py

```
class ContactPerson(models.Model):

client = models.ForeignKey(Client, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
salutation = models.CharField(max_length=4, choices=SALUTATIONS)
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=128)
email = models.EmailField()
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
mobile_number = models.CharField(max_length=20)
skype_name = models.CharField(_('Skype Name / Number'), max_length=128)
designation = models.CharField(max_length=128)
department = models.CharField(max_length=128, null=True)
```

Comment: Can you post your model code too? This is happens when any of the input data not passing cleaned_data filter

Answer (score 0):

You may add a custom FormSet by inheriting `BaseInlineFormSet` and make use of the property `has_changed()`

```
class ContactPersonFormSet(forms.BaseInlineFormSet):
    def clean(self):

        if self.has_changed() == False:
            raise forms.ValidationError('Please add at least one contact person.')
```

and then specify it in your fomset_facotry, like

```
ContactPersonFormSet = inlineformset_factory(Client, ContactPerson, form=ContactPersonForm, formset=ContactPersonFormSet, extra=1)
```

Comment: where is this class ContactPersonFormSet is to be written in forms.py or views.py

Comment: You may write it anywhere before 'using' it in the code. I'd prefer to write it in forms.py and then import the same to views.py.